# Принадлежит ли начало координат треугольнику?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу на Visual C++.

**Вот условия**:

> Даны действительные числа
> х1, х2, х3, у1, у2, у3. Принадлежит ли
> начало координат треугольнику с
> вершинами (х1;y1); (x2;y2); (x3;y3).

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @ROm4ik_1, расскажите, что у вас не получается или ваши мысли по решению задачи.

Comment: Ну а самому подумать? Хоть немного?

Comment: Не кипятись =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший для понимания вариант:
Находим площади четырех треугольников:

```
S1 (х1;y1); (x2;y2); (x3;y3)
S2 (0;0); (x2;y2); (x3;y3)
S3 (х1;y1); (0;0); (x3;y3)
S4 (х1;y1); (x2;y2); (0;0)
```

По формуле, например, такой: S = sqrt(p * (p-a) * (p-b) * (p-c))

Если s2+s3+s4 == s1, то да, пренадлежит.

Доказательство, надеюсь, не требуется? =)